# Magento. How to edit header

Tags: magento

In customer.xml file I copy

```
<default>
<!-- Mage_Customer -->
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
</reference>
```

and change title to TEST. How can I link this title to page `https://abcde.com/test/`?

Comment: these are menu , can not be called directly.
explain what you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find it. Solution:

```
    <default>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>TEST</label><url>test</url><title>TEST</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```